# If I update my Play Store-published Android App with *drastic* changes, will Google take it down?

Tags: android, android-studio

With the same keystore file, properly mentioned updated version number (and all stuff like that), if I make drastic changes to my app (such as make a 'proper' app with activities instead of rendering website using webview), will Google allow me to do so? I've been through the developer policies and there's no mention of it, but I don't want to take any risks.

To clarify, my app will be about the same content as before, but now instead of displaying a mere website inside, it will be an actual, full fledged app. Are there any rules regarding this case I should abide by?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but with drastic changes they have to go through rigorous testing again like the first time you release the app.